# Count number grep matches?

Tags: regex, perl, hash, grep

If I do the following, the `$c` becomes `1` where I was hoping it would be `2`, as a compact way to count the number of `grep` matches.

```
my %h = (
    "abc" => undef,
    "abcd" => undef,
    "abcde" => undef
);

my $c = 0;
$c++ if grep {/bcd/} keys %h;
print $c;
```

What would be the correct way to count the number of `grep` matches in this case?

Comment: You were thinking of `$c++ for grep {/bcd/} keys %h;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just assign counter to grep,

```
my $c = grep {/bcd/} keys %h;
```

From [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

> In scalar context, returns the number of times the expression was true.

Comment: What if there is more than one occurrence of 'c' in the keys?

Comment: @perlsufi `'c'` is not matched by the regex `/bcd/`.

Comment: sorry i meant the string for the grep, 'bcd'. Will it match all the times 'bcd' occurs in the keys? IE, "abcdabcdbcd" ?

Comment: @perlsufi it would count only one match perl list element.

Comment: @perlsufi, `grep` filters scalars; `grep` doesn't perform regex matches. As such, it returns the number of scalars remaining, not the number of occurrences of some string in others.